# Prove that $\frac{1+x_1^2}{1+x_1x_2} + \frac{1+x_2^2}{1+x_2x_3} + ... + \frac{1+x_{2020}^2}{1+x_{2020}x_{1}} \geq 2020$

Tags: inequality

Given $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{2020}$ as positive real numbers. Prove that $$\frac{1+x_1^2}{1+x_1x_2} + \frac{1+x_2^2}{1+x_2x_3} + ... + \frac{1+x_{2020}^2}{1+x_{2020}x_{1}} \geq 2020$$
Only use AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz and Bunyakovsky inequalities. No more than that.

Currently I don't know anything besides the equal sign will occur when $x_1=x_2=...=x_{2020}$.

Comment: [Similar but not same problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1633907p10268571) Consider some of the ideas used here. Adding an attempt may be beneficial, I believe the direction taken is standard.

Comment: Split the fractions. Use AM HM when the numerator is 1.

Comment: @TheBestMagician Can you add your approach? I couldn't push through with splitting the terms. $\quad$ I ended up with $ ( \sum x_i)^2 \geq n \sum x_i x_{i+1}$, which isn't true EG $ n = 5,  ( 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 )$.

Comment: Same problem on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1634929p10278399

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Major hint:** Show that (via CS if desired) $ (1 + x_1x_2)^2 \leq ( 1 + x_1^2)(1+x_2^2)$ with equality iff $ x_1 = x_2$.

Approach 1:  Using this to replace the denominator term wise, the result follows by applying AM-GM.

> $$ \sum \frac{ 1 + x_i^2 } { 1 + x_i x_{i+1} }  \geq \sum \sqrt{ \frac{ 1 + x_i^2 } { 1 + x_{i+1}^2 }} \geq n \sqrt[n]{ \prod \frac{ 1 + x_i^2 } { 1 + x_{i+1}^2 }} = n  $$

The equality case is when $ x_i$ are all the same.

---

Approach 2: Apply AM-GM directly to the LHS, then apply the hint.

> $$ \sum \frac{ 1 + x_i^2 } { 1 + x_i x_{i+1} } \geq n \sqrt[n] {\prod  \frac{ 1 + x_i^2 } { 1 + x_i x_{i+1} }} \geq n. $$

(Sorry, found this method later. Was preoccupied with splitting the numerator per the comments.)